# Visual Studio - Create -> New Project Dialog without ProjectTemplate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, project-template

I'm working a bit on CodeGeneration and Visual Studio integration- -> And I need some help...

Since I`m working on it, most of the time I used Visual Studios vsix-projects and ProjectTemplates to create new ProjectTemplates as Visual Studio Extension.

But know I'm wondering if it's possible to create a "Add new Project" Dialog without using a ProjectTemplates in the vsix. Cause I don't want to a have a"standard" project in my solution which is automatically created from the template. I just want to call a Wizard which simply implements the IWizard interface and does all the solution creation process.

So, is there a possibility to create a "New Project" entry without having a ProjectTemplate  ?

Hope you can guess what I'm trying to say ;-)

Thanks for your help :-)

[Edit-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]

To make my explanation easier to understand.. Sorry guys...

This is the normal ProjectTemplate process with a wizard (IWizard)
[image]

What I'm trying to do is something like this
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for this? - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx

Comment: Sorry, no. The ProjectTemplates represents a project which is going to be generated. I need something without it. Maybe a "EmptySolutionTemplate"

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to create blank solutions try this -

```
New Project >> Other Project Types >> Visual Studio Solutions >> Blank Solution
```

[image]

The solution will be blank -

[image]